# Kentico Unigrid OnExternalDataBound's checkbox controls don't get refreshed after sorting

Tags: c#, .net, kentico, unigrid

There is a an issue with customized check-boxes in Kentico unigrid control as below:

when I use checkbox control within OnExternalDataBound function, everything is OK except when I click on any sort links, the value of check boxes remain the same!?

*example: when I make a selection (e.g. the first three items) and then sort the grid, the first three items are still selected even though those are now no longer the three I chose before sorting.*

```
 protected object unigridXXX_OnExternalDataBound(object sender, string sourceName, object parameter)
 {
    var drv = (DataRowView)parameter;
    var obj = (DataControlFieldCell)sender;
    int reviewId = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(drv.Row["ItemID"], 0);
    bool isExcludedFromEmail = ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(drv.Row["EmailExclusion"], false);

    if (sourceName.ToLower() == "excludedemail")
    {
        CheckBox chkEmailExclusion = new CheckBox();
        chkEmailExclusion.Enabled = true;

        if (isAdmin || (isTrainingAdmin))
        {
            chkEmailExclusion.ID = "chkEmailExclusion";
            chkEmailExclusion.TextAlign = TextAlign.Left;
            chkEmailExclusion.Enabled = false;
            chkEmailExclusion.CssClass = "excluded-email";
            chkEmailExclusion.Checked = isExcludedFromEmail;
        }

        return chkEmailExclusion;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this is a known bug and there is a workaround for that.

**Please NOTE: this problem is only for checkbox and possibly textbox controls bot not any other controls.**

I'm using Kentico v8.2.16

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the identifier of the checkbox unique. Otherwise viewstate can't be loaded properly.

Use something like this:

```
chkEmailExclusion.ID = "chkEmailExclusion_" + reviewId ;
```

Also, set the ID outside the condition. Right after `chkEmailExclusion.Enabled = true;`.

Comment: Spot on! the problem was when I checked the auto allocated IDs on the browser source code and all of them were unique however this was the problem for ViewState. I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks Man!